Laravel showing only Homepage and all other routes showing 404 on shared hosting
I am using ionos shared hosting and pointing my subdomain to laravel and react public folder but only / homepage is working all else is showing 404. I tried to dd on /welcome route but i see it's not even pointing index.php. Also uploaded the production files of js to run the router.js that i believe it should first point to index.php  but it's not doing that.
What can possibly go wrong?
.htaccess file here:
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
 </IfModule>


Have you verified .htaccess is enabled and working on the server? "I tried to dd on /welcome route but i see it's not even pointing index.php" - what does that mean?

it's mean server pointing homepage / route to index.php not any other routes like /welcome according to laravel lifecycle every request land on index.php first then it goes further!

Please check it will work:

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/ 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f



RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 
#RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ public/index.php [L] 
</IfModule>

